# Pipe Curl Output with Grep ending o Txt File in Ruby

Tags: ruby, curl, grep, sinatra, jq

im encountering problems using curl within ruby. I want to run a ruby script and it should store a JSON type object like this

```
{
    "remote":  [
        {"name": "cast-1",
         "id": 1212
        },
        {"name": "cast-1",
         "id": 1214
        },
        {"name": "home-11",
         "id": 3212
        },
        {"name": "cast-3",
         "id": 3212
        },
        {"name": "cast-3",
         "id": 3213
        },
        {"name": "cast-4",
         "id": 4211
        }

    ]
}
```

in a text file. I mapped and grepped the curl input to get the desired entries.
Now when i run the script, my txt file pops out empty.
example of what i tried

```
#ruby

`curl -m 10 -s -H '[...]' "https://example_with_json_file.com" | jq -r .remote | group_by(.name) | map({ (.[0].name): map(.id) }) | "\(.[])" | grep '3\|4\|11' > file.txt` 

foo = []

File.open(file.txt) do |file|
  foo = file.readlines
end
[...]
```

running the above input in my temrinal works. I tried using Kernel.system order system within my ruby example. Nothing worked.

How can i pipe this output into a txt file

```
{"cast-3":[3212,3213]}
{"cast-4":[4211]}
{"home-11":[3212]}
```

Or in general, is it possible to run the curl input in a single line, that is executable using ruby?

Comment: Is this a ruby, curl, jq or grep question? Or do you expect us to debug your program and find the problem?

Comment: i want to pass everything to a ruby expression. so a ruby question.

Comment: the curl expression should function properly, as it is a shell command, in my ruby code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always it's better to do stuff in one language. Like:

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://path/to/json')
JSON.parse(response)
...
```

If you want mix it with Bash, try:

```
bar = `curl -m 10 -s -H '[...]' "https://example_with_json_file.com" | jq -r .remote | group_by(.name) | map({ (.[0].name): map(.id) }) | "\(.[])" | grep '3\|4\|11'`
foo = bar.split(/\n/)
File.write('/path/to/file', bar)
```